# error in ip address received

Tags: c, linux, ip-address, raw-sockets

I am implementing raw sockets in C. I have two programs (say server and client). Client is sending info to server and then server is sending ACK. Client has sent info and server has successfully received it. Now server is sending back ACK. Now, Client has parsed  ethernet header successfully. I have problem in receiving the IP address.

```
1. What should be the type of arguments of the function CreateIPHeader()?
2. How to print IP addresses in ParseIPHeader()?
3. What should be the data type of value returned by ParseIPHeader, if I want just the IP addresses?

struct iphdr *CreateIPHeader(char *src_ip,char *dst_ip)
{
struct iphdr *ip_header;
ip_header=malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr));
//OTHER FIELDS OF IP HEADER
ip_header->saddr = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)(src_ip)));
ip_header->daddr = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)(dst_ip)));
ip_header->check=ComputeChecksum((unsigned char *)ip_header,ip_header->ihl*4);
printf("\nip to be sent = %s",ip_header->saddr); //printing correct IP
printf("\nip to be rcvd = %s",ip_header->daddr);

return(ip_header);
}

char* ParseIPHeader(unsigned char *packet,int len)
{
struct iphdr *ip_header,*ret_ip;
unsigned char *out;
struct ethhdr *ethernet_header;
out=malloc(2048);
memset(out, 0, 2048);
ethernet_header=(struct ethhdr *) out;
ret_ip=(struct iphdr *) (out + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
if(ntohs(ethernet_header->h_proto)==ETH_P_IP)
{
    if(len>=(sizeof(struct ethhdr)+sizeof(struct iphdr)))
    {
        ip_header=(struct iphdr*)(packet+sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        ret_ip->saddr = ip_header->daddr;
            ret_ip->daddr = ip_header->saddr;
    printf("daddr SENT = %s",ret_ip->daddr);  //how to print them?
        printf("saddr SENT = %s",ret_ip->saddr);
    }
    else
    printf("IP packet does not have full header\n");
}
else
{ 
//not an IP packet
}
return out;
}


int main()
{
unsigned char in[2048];
int len;
char *rcv_ip;
Struct iphdr *ip_header;

    memset(in,0,2048);
len=recvfrom(raw,in,2048,0,(struct sockaddr *)&packet_info,&packet_info_size);
rcv_ip=ParseIPHeader(in,len); /*I want this function to return me the ip addresses which I would use in the next line.*/
ip_header =CreateIPHeader(rcv_ip+5,rcv_ip);

memset(in,0,2048);
memcpy(in+sizeof(struct ethhdr),ip_header,ip_header->ihl*4);

sendrawpacket(raw,in,pkt_len);
    free(ip_header);
return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: all those things are there as I have parsed ethernet address. Also, listen, accept, etc. calls are not used in raw sockets but sockets.

Comment: How is it possible that `printf("Dest IP address: %s \n",(abc->daddr));` is correct?  You are coercing `abc->daddr` into a C string, which is not going to work.  Please provide a SSCCE, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: @cklin How to give SSCCE? I am new here. Heard of this several times but don't know how to give it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: @cklin edited. Please see this once. Go through main function written in the last.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
printf("\nDest Addr %s \n",inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)&((ip_header->daddr)))));

printf("\nSource Addr %s \n",inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)&(ip_header->saddr))));
```

Perhaps:

```
printf("\nDest Addr %s \n",inet_ntoa(ip_header->daddr));

printf("\nSource Addr %s \n",inet_ntoa(ip_header->saddr));
```

Comment: *incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘inet_ntoa’* This is what I am getting

Answer (score 0):

If indeed the `printf` is causing you to segfault and not something else, then perhaps:

```
struct in_addr dest;
dest.s_addr = ip_header->daddr;
printf("\nDest Addr %s \n", inet_ntoa(dest));
```

This is because (assuming you are using `struct iphdr *ip_header`) `ip_header->daddr` has a type of `__u32` and `inet_ntoa` takes a `struct in_addr`.

Comment: So you're not actually segfaulting?  Without an SSCCE it's hard to help any further.

Comment: @user3392539 Perhaps you should tell us what actually happens. There has to be a change in output if this code is executed. But perhaps it isn't executed. So what happens ?

Comment: @nos I want parseipheader() to return me the ip address of both sender and receiver. What should be its return type? Can it be character array?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong.

1. `CreateIPHeader`

   You are confusing `inet_ntoa()` with `inet_aton()`. When creating the IP header, you want to set `ip_header->saddr` using something like

   ```
   inet_aton(src_ip, (struct in_addr *) &ip_header->saddr)
   ```

   Remember, the `s_addr` and `d_addr` in `struct iphdr` are of type `__u32`, not `char` arrays. Thus, when you make this change, the `printf` statements in `CreateIPHeader` will break.
2. `main`

   The reason why your `printf`'s are working is due to Problem #1.  On receive, you call `CreateIPHeader` to create an incorrect `struct iphdr` (see above), which now incorrectly has C-strings assigned to `saddr` and `daddr`.  Later, `abc` points to this incorrect header; your `printf`'s magically work because `abc->saddr` and `abc->daddr` actually *are* C strings.
3. You are only overwriting the `iphdr` portion of packet_buffer (your `memcpy` statement).  You must also change the `h_dest` and `h_src` values in `struct ethhdr`.
4. You really don't need to convert the IP addresses into a C string and then convert them back into IP addresses.
5. Also, you aren't freeing `ip_header`.

In general, you can do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char in[2048];
    unsigned char out[2048];
    int len;

    memset(in, 0, 2048);
    memset(out, 0, 2048);

    len = recvfrom(raw, in, 2048, 0, 
               (struct sockaddr *) &packet_info, &packet_info_size);

    struct ethhdr *in_eth = (struct ethhdr *) in;
    if (ntohs(ethernet_header->h_proto) == ETH_P_IP && 
        len >= sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr) {
            struct iphdr *in_ip = (struct iphdr*) (in + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

            /* create outbound packet, starting with eth header */
            struct ethhdr *out_eth = (struct ethhdr *) out;
            /* ... set h_dest and h_src */

            struct iphdr *out_ip = (struct iphdr *) (out + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
            out_ip->saddr = in_ip->daddr;
            out_ip->daddr = in_ip->saddr;
            /* calculate the IPv4 checksum, packet len etc */

            sendrawpacket(raw, out, pkt_len);
        }

    return 0;
};
```

No guarantee that's bug-free.  Just wrote it in the browser.

Comment: edited again with as much I could understand. Since I am doing raw socket programming the first time so a bit confused. Please help me by giving the answer of first three questions I updated in my post. :)